# JavaScript DataTable custom Filter is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am binding data in Datatable using Ajax in JavaScript. Now i want to introduce Custom filter so user can filter the data based on Date Range.

```
  var table2 = $('#example').DataTable();
            table2.clear();
            table2.destroy();
            $('#example').remove();
```

So first of all i am clearing and destroying current table and then i am binding datatable again but somehow it is creating only header row, no any data rows.

So can you please guide me to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you tried $('#example').fnDestroy(); ??

Comment: yes but it is showing me below error:
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable.fnDestroy is not a function

Comment: you have to do exist check .. can you please prepare a fiddle with your codes?

Comment: @Hiren please go through below link given it will help you If not let me know will help you ?.try to give fiddle link of your code Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some more code please?  there not much to work with there...